# Gradle extremely high resource usage

Tags: android, performance, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.1

Gradle builds are taking too long and eating more than half of my computer resources.

When I run Gradle build it takes more than 5-6 minutes and everything begin to hang. I cant even scroll down in a web page.

[image]

I am running only Android Studio and chrome on my machine. Please help me it is extremely frustrating and killing my machine.

Comment: Is everything up to date? Android Studio/Gradle? Java? are you running any emulators? Android Studio is very resource intensive sometimes. I have 16GB RAM and am always hovering around 11 when Android studio is open. (including chrome with 11ish tabs)

Comment: I am using gradle version 2.1.2 and Android studio  2.1.2

Comment: Are you using Multidex?